# How can I leave vertical space in one item of an enumerate?

Tags: formatting, lists, enumerate

I want to leave some vertical space after an item in an enumerate so that I can draw a diagram by hand there after I print out my document. Basically, I want the next item to show up as if I have text in the previous item. I kind of simulated what I want by adding some periods in this example (but I just want blank space):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \item .

  .

  .
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Use `\vspace*{3cm}`, where `3cm` is changed to whatever space you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \item \leavevmode\vspace{3cm}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]